# Test of node.js method using knex with sqlite3 never stops

Tags: node.js, sqlite, testing, knex.js

### What I want to do

I'm trying to test a `node.js` function which uses `knex`.

Instead of just mocking `knex`, I think it's interesting to actually run the test on an in-memory database, which makes this test not strictly unitary, but it's, to me, the only useful way to test a `repository` class.

It's also the most voted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749601/1187067

### What I use in my test

- A simplified book repository `bookRepo.js` based on `knex`
- A test `bookRepo.test.js` injecting a `knex` connection based on `SQLite3`.

### Problem

The database is well initialize, the test succeeds and the `afterEach()` function is well invoked, but the process **never ends** which is particularly problematic for pipelines.

The only way I found to stop the process is to call `knex.destroy()` in both bookRepo.js and bookRepo.test.js, but it is not possible to destroy knex because it won’t be possible to use it more than once.

Thanks for helping!

### Code

**bookRepo.js**

```js
const knex = require('connection'); // dependency not injected in constructor

const TABLE = 'books';

class BookRepo {
  constructor() {
    this.knex = knex;
  }

  static getTable() {
    return TABLE;
  }

  async getTitleById(id) {
    const book = await this.knex(TABLE)
      .select('title')
      .where('id', id)
      .first();

    return book.title;
  }
}

module.exports = BookRepo;
```

**bookRepo.test.js**

```js
const { assert } = require('chai');
const mock = require('mock-require');
const {
  describe,
  it,
  before,
  after,
  beforeEach,
  afterEach,
} = require('mocha');

const sqliteConf = {
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: ':memory:',
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true,
};
const knex = require('knex')(sqliteConf);

const booksTable = BookRepo.getTable();
const BOOK_1 = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Batman',
};

let bookRepo;

describe('getTitleById', () => {
  before(() => {
    // To use sqlite3 in the tested module, replace knexfile (required by connections)
    mock('../knexfile', {
      development: sqliteConf,
    });

    // as knex is not injected in constructor, we need to require BookRepo after having mocked knexfile.
    const BookRepo = require('../bookRepo');
    bookRepo = new BookRepo();
  });

  after(() => {
    mock.stopAll();
    knex.destroy(); // destroys only the connection of the test, not in bookRepo
  });

  /**
   * We initialize the SQLite database before each test (create table and insert)
   */
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // drop table
    await knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(booksTable);

    // create table
    await knex.schema.createTable(booksTable, (table) => {
      table.integer('id');
      table.string('title');
    });

    // Insertion
    await knex.transaction((t) => knex(booksTable)
      .transacting(t)
      .insert(BOOK_1)
      .then(t.commit)
      .catch(t.rollback))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        throw new Error('failed to insert test data');
      });
  });

  /**
   * We drop the SQLite table after each test
   */
  afterEach(async () => {
    await knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(booksTable); // table well dropped
  });

  it('returns the title of the given book', async () => {
    const bookRepo = new BookRepo();

    const expectedTitle = BOOK_1.title;
    const retrievedTitle = await bookRepo.getTitleById(BOOK_1.id);

    assert.equal(retrievedTitle, expectedTitle); // OK
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
…
dependencies": {
    "knex": "^0.20.1",
 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "latest",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "sqlite3": "latest",
  }
}
```

Comment: update: adding the following configuration seems to fix the issue: `pool: { min: 0, idleTimeoutMillis: 500},`

Comment: Note that this issue could be avoided if knex was injected to the bookRepo.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using mocha, it seems best to use Mocha's [`after` hook](https://mochajs.org/index.html#hooks) and call `destroy` from there. Likewise, you could instantiate Knex in `before`. I can't think of a reason you would need to call `destroy` in your non-test code.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right, I can actually call destroy in the after hook and it works here since knex is injected to the bookRepo.
Actually I should have required knex in the bookRepo as well, which is the exact situation I need to answer to. In this situation destroy in after hook is not enough unfortunately.
However, it's still possible to add a `setKnex(knex)` in bookrepo to allow injection in tests.

Comment: You can also inject with a default if that's your preference, so `thingThatNeedsKnex(db = realConnection)`, and if you pass in a connection it'll use that instead of your standard one.